# How to retain both the values of Enter pressed on Subfile and F5 pressed on Popup

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a display file in which both subfile and window exists. When I take F5 on the popup, 369 position in INFDS is getting populated with hex value of F5(x'35'). Is there any way to find whether an Enter was hit on the subfile before the window was displayed without using any work variable?

Comment: Show us some code and ask a specific question about the code. Otherwise the best I can do is say probably not, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, probably not, but it will depend on the flow of your application.

Without seeing code, I can't do anything but guess how things are working for you, but here is that guess. When F5 is pressed, the keyboard is locked, and control returns back to the program. The program then displays the window and unlocks the keyboard to allow additional user entry. Now there is a feature in IBM i that allows keystrokes to be buffered while the keyboard is locked, but that doesn't matter, all keystrokes up to the next command key will be played to the window rather than to the subfile.